# Pattern matching with regex on article reference

Tags: php, regex

I need to pattern match in PHP against many article references in a given string and I want to extract them afterwards. The references can have up to 16 digits and each of them can have different values. One thing to know : starting from (and including) digit 11, everything can be optional in the incoming data (but if you have something valid after an optional digit then this digit is necessarily "-"). In addition, if you have "-" up until the end, the reference can be truncated. For example :

**A2--L3500XM-----** can be **A2--L3500XM**

**D4--L4652Z-4----** can be **D4--L4652Z-4**

**A3--L5020MW4---A** stays **A3--L5020MW4---A**

These are all valid references. Here's what I've been working on so far :

```
[DA][1-5][V\-][AN\-][LMFGHN][\d]{4}[H-RT-ZBD]([H-RT-ZBD\-]?)(?(-1)[1-4\-]?)
```

I'm up to the 11th digit but this is where it gets tricky. Here is my sample references :

> ```
> D1--L6000T-4       VALID
> D1--L6000T         VALID
> D1--L6000T4-----   INVALID
> D1--L6000T-----    VALID
> ```

I've annotated with VALID the ones that **should** be matched. My issue is that my regex takes **all** of them (truncating the "-" as expected), but the third one **shouldn't** be matched since 4 isn't valid for the 11th digit. 
I think the reason it does take the 4 is because 10th digit is optional, which means that if it's not there I guess the -1 could be refering to *[H-RT-ZBD]*, which contains nearly the same characters ? 
So I'm a bit lost here and my questions are : How can I achieve this ? Is there an easier way ? Can it even be done ?

Pattern rules :

```
digit number : pattern
1 :   [DA]
2 :   [1-5]
3 :   [V-]
4 :   [AN-]
5 :   [LMFGHN]
6-9 : \d{4}
10 :  [H-RT-ZBD]
11 :  [H-RT-ZBD-]?
12 :  [1-4-]?
13 :  [KRX-]?
14 :  [CPW-]?
15 :  [MT-]?
16 :  [A-C-]?
```

Typically the input strings to match is a plain table with a lot of spaces and potentially any characters.

Comment: When you say "everything can be optional" what does the pattern look like? In your 3rd example, why isn't 4 a valid entry for the 11th symbol? Do you have a specific interpretation of what this patterns rules are? it seems to me 4 examples is nowhere near enough.

Comment: +1 because you clearly explained your problem, posted informations about valid inputs and expected outputs, and what you've tried so far to solve your problem, which didn't work as expected. Congratulations, your question should be taken as an example by many many others!

Comment: @melwil The rules are in the regex, each bracket is a digit. 11th digit should be [H-RT-ZBD\-]. But since it's optional, then the conditional subpattern can behave unexpectedly. And yes I will need more example  for the following digits but it's useless if I can't even get past this one.

Comment: What is that `(?(-1)…)` modifier? Never seen that syntax.

Comment: @Bergi See http://www.asiteaboutnothing.net/regex/regex-conditionals.html

Comment: @Shinosha so the 11th digit, and up to the 16th digit is optional? can it be 13 or 15 long? What is this `(?(-1)[1-4\-]?)` supposed to match? I think many of your problems can be solved by anchoring your search, i.e. `^` and `$` to force the match to evaluate the entire string.

Comment: Yes and yes (see examples in my post). The (-1) refers to the preceding group, so basically this means match "[1-4\-]?" only if preceding group has been matched. The preceding group here is "[H-RT-ZBD\-]?" but since it's optional I guess the subpattern can refer to "[H-RT-ZBD]", which sucks.

Comment: if 11th digit is optional, then it can't match the 12th digit, right?

Comment: If the 11th isn't there at all yes. This works in the same way for the  13->16 digits. For example the 14th digit can't exist if all the digits before him don't. And by exist I mean have been matched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following regex evaluates true for all the rules and input you presented. You can copy this entire block and use it, including the comments.

```
$string = "D1--L6000T4------ A3--L5020MW4---A D4--L4652Z-4---- D1--L6000T";

preg_match_all(
    '/(                  # Matching the start of the group
       [DA]              # Digit 1
       [1-5]             # Digit 2
       [V-]              # Digit 3
       [AN-]             # Digit 4
       [LMFGHN]          # Digit 5
       \d{4}             # Digit 6-9
       [H-RT-ZBD]        # Digit 10
    (?:[H-RT-ZBD-]       # Digit 11
    (?:[1-4-]            # Digit 12
    (?:[KRX-]            # Digit 13
    (?:[CPW-]            # Digit 14
    (?:[MT-]             # Digit 15
       [A-C-]            # Digit 16
    ?)?)?)?)?)?)         # Closing all the groups and alternations
    (?:(?=(\s|%20))|$    # Matching a space (even %20) or end of string. This is done to exclude partial matches.
    )/x', 
    $string, $matches
);

var_dump($matches);
```

---

**A few notes on what I changed.**

Removed escaping of the dash inside character groups. If it is put in a place where it doesn't mark an interval, it will be like any other character.

Removed the character group `[ ]` around `\d`.

Instead of having the 11th digit optional, I write out how the pattern could be different from 11 and out. The recursive optionality of groups makes sure that if the 12th character is able to match, it needs the 11th, and so on.

**The end boundary**

I've added `(?:(?=(\s|%20))|$` to the end of the regex, which makes sure this pattern will only match if it doesn't have following characters that would otherwise be part of the pattern. Doing this is the only way to discount partial matches such as `D1--L6000T` in `D1--L6000T4------` when you cannot guarantee that each pattern will be separated by spaces. Which frankly I find strange.

**Retrieval of matches**

The regex is constructed so that the complete pattern will be available as the matched part, or index 0 in a match array.

Comment: the `^` and `$` won't work if the pattern is used to extract patterns from a string, you could use `(?:^|[^A-Z])` and `(?:[A-Z]-|$)` instead for the respective start and end of matched string

Comment: i meant `(?:^|[^A-Z])` and `(?:[^A-Z]-|$)`

Comment: Looks pretty good ! Although I'm gonna try the divide and conquer alternative from @Jack first since it's a bit more maintainable. Here's a +1 anyway.

Comment: Thanks, but all you have to do is divide mine up on different lines and add the `/x` flag though. His does not have the alternation of the last 6 digits. I can split it on lines for you if you'd like that.

Comment: @Jack I'm assuming that, yes. If the patterns are part of some bigger string, then how can you ever be sure they meant it to match an article? I wrote in my answer that I did this, and how it could be changed or removed. Also you are doing it in two rounds, mine validates one value immediately.

Comment: If you try to match it against my example string `'D1--L6000T4------ A3--L5020MW4---A D4--L4652Z-4----'`, your expression only matches `A3--L5020MW4---A` whereas it should also match `D4--L4652Z-4----`.

Comment: Ok, fair enough, the boundaries were bad. I'll update the answer then, with the php code I used.

Comment: You've got a point about the optional characters, not sure why I read past that :(

Comment: It happens. I think mine is the better answer though, since it solves the issue straight up.

Comment: Close but there is an issue with "D4--L4652Z-4----". It's only taking up to the first "-".

Comment: I'm sorry, I disallowed space, and it was the last item on my testing, so it validated against `$`. Should be ok now.

Comment: Actually, [this expression](http://codepad.org/1O0BUTPR) should work just as well ... don't mind codepad.org's misconfigured pcre ;-) anyway, +1

Comment: @Jack Something unexpected : Admit this one D1V-L0300PH-KPMA. Replace the H by a Y for example and it takes everything before it where it should take none. Same behavior for the next digits. Seems like the end boundary is responsible. But if I touch it then stuff like D1V-L0300PH-KPMA%20 gets entirely ignored.

Comment: @Jack you can't have word boundary alone as end match, because the space between `A-` is also a word boundary, which will cut many patterns in half and validate erroneously.

Comment: Ah okay, it seemed to work, but that would indeed be problematic.

Comment: @Shinosha you should choose an answer if you got your problem solved. Or did you have any issues still?

Comment: @melwil Yes, see my comment above.

Comment: @Shinosha I cannot reproduce that, it still matches both `D1V-L0300PH-KPMA` `D1V-L0300PY-KPMA` just fine.

Comment: @melwil Weird, try with D1V-L0300PH-aPMA. It's gonna match the valid part but it shoudn't.

Comment: @Shinosha just for curiosity sake, will each of these references be separated by spaces? The reason why that matches is because someone pointed out that it should be able to match valid references inside a string. If you always have spaces at least after a reference, then it would be a much safer match. Right now a lot of special cases will probably match this wrongly. Are there spaces after every reference?

Comment: Well, a chunck of text is gonna be sent over AJAX with JQuery so spaces are gonna be escaped by "%20". But although this is very likely because of the way the origin text is formatted, this is not mandatory. Of course if this is too much of a pain, I'll just deal with it.

Comment: I can accept %20 as a reference termination. Let me update the regex quick. EDIT: try now.

Comment: Works good, I'll just use % however. Might as well go for matching any escaped character as end of match. I'll test it in real conditions tomorrow just to be sure. But this definitely looks good.

Answer (score 1):

> I guess the -1 could be refering to `[H-RT-ZBD]`, which contains nearly the same characters?

No, it does indeed refer to `([H-RT-ZBD\-]?)` which was the last capturing group. Yet, it always matches since the letter is optional - then the empty string is captured. And your conditional is true.

I guess instead of capturing an optional character you should make your character-capturing group optional (see http://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html for the differences). So try

```
[DA][1-5][V-][AN-][LMFGHN]\d{4}[H-RT-ZBD]([H-RT-ZBD-])?(?(-1)([1-4-]))?(?(-1)([KRX-]))?(?(-1)([CPW-]))?(?(-1)([MT-]))?(?(-1)[A-C-])?
```

And if you do not need the capturing groups, you could simplify the expression by using more natural nesting instead of conditionals:

```
[DA][1-5][V-][AN-][LMFGHN]\d{4}[H-RT-ZBD](?:[H-RT-ZBD-](?:[1-4-](?:[KRX-](?:[CPW-](?:[MT-][A-C-]?)?)?)?)?)?
```

And of course you will have to [anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) your expression in any case so that is would not match valid subparts of invalid input :-) You might wrap it in `^`+`$`, `(?<!\S)`+`(?!\S)` or `(?<=\s|^)`+`(?=\s|$)`.

Comment: But then the invalid "D1--L6000T4-----" gets matched as "D1--L6000T", whereas it should not match at all.

Comment: @Jack Correct. I'm glad to see I made some kind of sense at all.

Comment: @Shinosha I would suggest to write an expression that matches the whole 16 char section and then validate each individual match separately.

Comment: @Jack: Yes, but only if you don't anchor the expression (which I had implicitly expected)

Comment: @Jack You mean get the mandatory stuff and any 6 characters afterwards and then apply another expression for each reference ? I don't see how that would avoid unwanted valid reference.

Comment: @Shinosha Because then you can use anchored expressions :)

Answer (score -1):

You should use the regex only for selecting likely patterns, for extracting them from the original string.

After you have the array of selected potential patterns, use `IF` and `SWITCH` statements, along with `substr` and other string comparison functions to determine if each of the patterns is valid.

Otherwise you risk writing overly complex regular expressions that will take too long to debug, too long to update and nobody will want to use your code afterwards.

Comment: If I do this I could have a valid pattern extracted from an invalid one. And I don't want that because that could end up creating unwanted article.

Comment: which is why you use conditional logic to determine if the selected matches are correct - it depends if you are confident that your regex will be 100% correct, of if you want to add some additional validation logic in to check the selections it makes, in which case you can make your regex simpler and easier to read, (making it easier to update) and make your PHP logic more complex, enabling you to more easily comment and document your code, explaining each process you are using to validate the input.